# How to remove accents from a file using a cron job?

Tags: bash, shell, sed, diacritics, iconv

I have a .sh file that convert accents into unaccent chars using iconv, so I have this file:

```
$FUT2
#Containing
<span>Panamá</span>
```

Running the .sh manually from the command line:

```
#!/bin/sh
iconv -f utf8 -t ascii//TRANSLIT "$FUT2" > "$FUT"
```

I get in the file:

**`<span>Panama</span>`**

Thats nice, but when I run it from the cron, using webmin and setting up a scheduled cron job, then i get:

**`<span>Panam?</span>`**

and, if I use sed

Running the .sh manually from the command line:

```
#!/bin/sh
sed -e 's/[á]/a/g;s/[é]/e/g;s/[í]/i/g;s/[ó]/o/g;s/[ú]/u/g'  "$FUT2" > "$FUT"
```

**`<span>Panama</span>`**

Running from webmin

**`<span>Panamaa</span>`**

The .sh its UTF-8 without BOM

So any idea how to fix it or any other way how to replace the accents?
**Thanks**

Comment: you're probably ending up with unicode corruption: since you mention webmin, you've got an entire http pipeline involved, and SOME stage of the process is using a different charset than the rest.

Comment: What does your cron job look like? If it is some HTTP nonsense, can you try using a crontab from the command line instead?

Comment: I think this question could be "Why does characters don't work for a script invoked from a cron job?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try to set the var LANG=en_US.UTF-8 in the crontab command?

```
0 5 * * 1 LANG=en_US.UTF-8 iconv -f utf8 -t ascii//TRANSLIT "file1" > "file2"
```